# File Upload System not working quite right... can someone look at this code?

Tags: java, php, file-upload

I created some code to handle basic file upload from a java client to a php server, but I'm having some issues with the naming and directory creation. Here is the important parts of the code:

The method I use to upload the file:

```
public static void uploadWithInfo(Uri uri, String title, String artist, String description) {
    try {
        String path = uri.getPath();
        File file = new File(path);
        URL url = new URL("http://**********/upload.php?title="+title+"&artist="+artist+"&description="+description);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        int totalbytes = bis.available();

        for(int i = 0; i < totalbytes; i++) {
            os.write(bis.read());
        }
        os.close();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String serverResponse = "";
        String response = "";

        while((response = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            serverResponse = serverResponse + response;
        }
        reader.close();
        bis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It's just supposed to upload an audio file. The user inputs the artist, title, and a very short description if necessary. The actual file is uploaded just fine so I don't think any more java is necessary. Here is the code on the php end:

```
<?php

$uploadBase = "music/";
$uploadFolder = $_GET['artist']+"/";
$uploadFileName = $_GET['title'];
$uploadFileDescription = $_GET['description'];
$uploadPath = $uploadBase.$uploadFolder.$uploadFileName."%%D%%=".$uploadFileDescription.".mp3";

if(!is_dir($uploadBase)) {
    mkdir($uploadBase);
}

if(!is_dir($uploadFolder)) {
    mkdir($uploadFolder);
}

$incomingData = file_get_contents('php://input');

if(!$incomingData) {
    die("No data.");
}

$fh = fopen($uploadPath, 'w') or die("Error opening path.");
fwrite($fh, $incomingData) or die("Error writing file.");
fclose($fh) or die("Error closing shop.");

echo "Success!";

?>
```

So I get all of the inputted values for title, artist, and description. Then I create 2 directories if they don't already exist: one for music and one for the artist the uploader input. Then I create a path of base(music)/folder(artist)/filename(title)"code to let me parse description"(%%D%%).mp3.

So a song Billie Jean by Michael Jackson with a description "favorite" should have a path of

`music/Michael Jackson/Billie%20Jean%%D%%favorite.mp3`

What I get however, is:

`music/0Billie%%D%%=`

The directory for artist is not created, there is a weird 0 before the title (which only includes the first word), and the description doesn't show.

I don't really know where I went wrong, can anyone give me some insight? Thank you.

Comment: Your issue is hard to understand. Please update your question to add debug prints of 1) the entire URL in Java (including encoded parameters), 2) the raw parameters as PHP has retrieved and 3) the `realpath()` of the paths.

Comment: It looks like an encoding issue. The URL as assembled by Java might lack urlencoding. It could also contain a `\0` NUL byte, which leads to the cut off filename. Apply input filtering (`\w+` regex) on the $_GET vars in any case.

Comment: I hate to sound like a fool but I'm quite new at this and I really don't know what either of your comments are asking for when you say `realpath()` and `(\w regex)`. The encoding thing may be the issue, I'll include my full upload method from java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a stupid error with some related php code. Sorry to trouble you all.

Answer (score 0):

Your InputStream.available() method does not do what you expect it to. Use the File size instead.

**Edit:**Use a multi-part upload instead. The Apache HttpClient supports it, google for [examples](http://indiwiz.com/2009/02/11/multi-part-content-upload-in-apache-http-components-http-client/).

Comment: I'll do that but the upload itself is working just fine, its the naming where I am having trouble.